# how to call the observer after checkout and store the orderid in my custom collection?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, event-observer, onepage-checkout, checkbox

I want to save the order id and quote id in my custom table(collection).Give me some solution.
My observer function is

```
public function placeOrderAfter($event) {

        try {

            $order_id = $event->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId();
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
            $quote_id = $order->getQuoteId();           
           Mage::helper("comp/connection")->updatesaveorder($order_id,$order->getCustomerId());

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }

}`
```

after putting this code order is not placed .

Comment: What is your problem? Any error? Exception? What is in the log? What have you expected, what happened instead? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using observer event `"sales_order_place_after"` you can save data in your custom table.

In your module's app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml add code like

```
<events>
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <namespace_module_order_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>module/observer</class>
                    <method>customOrderSave</method>
                </namespace_module_order_observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
</events>
```

Create observer file app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model/Observer.php:

```
public function customOrderSave($observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getOrder();
    //add your code here
}
```

}

Comment: may be it throws error in updatesaveorder() function. Please check error log